# Can't bind to 'fa' since it isn't a known property of 'i'

Tags: angular, typescript

This is not the font awesome plugin. This is something I wrote myself. When I add it to AppModule, it doesn't work.

**AppModule**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { DataModule } from './data/data.module';
import { NavtreeComponent } from './sidebar/navtree.component';
import { JsonifyPipe } from './jsonify.pipe';
import { DebugPipe } from './debug.pipe';
import { PagesModule } from './pages/pages.module';
import { PanelsComponent } from './panels/panels.component';
import { IsolateScrollDirective } from './controls/isolate-scroll.directive';
import { FontAwesomeDirective, FontAwesomeLinkComponent } from './controls/font-awesome.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    NavtreeComponent,
    JsonifyPipe,
    DebugPipe,
    PanelsComponent,
    IsolateScrollDirective,
    FontAwesomeDirective, 
    FontAwesomeLinkComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule,
    DataModule.forRoot(),
    PagesModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**font-awesome.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Directive, ElementRef, Input, HostListener, OnInit, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';

import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'a[fa]',
    template: 
`<i [fa]="fa" 
    [@spinonce]="fa === 'refresh' ? clicked : 0"
    (@spinonce.done)="clicked=0"></i>
`,

    animations: [
        trigger('spinonce', [
            //state("void", style({
            //    transform: 'rotate(0deg)'
            //})),
            transition('0 => 1', [
                animate('1000ms ease-in-out', style({
                    transform: 'rotate(360deg)'
                }))
            ]),
        ])
    ]
})
export class FontAwesomeLinkComponent {
    @Input() fa: string;
    @Input() class: string;

    @HostBinding('class')
    get getClass(){
        return (this.class || '') + ' fa';
    }
    @HostBinding('attr.aria-hidden')
    get ariaHidden() {
        return true
    }

    @HostListener('click')
    onLinkClicked() {
        this.clicked++;
    }

    clicked = 0;
}


@Directive({
    selector: 'i[fa]'
})
export class FontAwesomeDirective {
    @Input() public fa: string;
    @Input() public class: string;
    @HostBinding('class')
    public get classStr() { 
        return 'fa fa-' + this.fa + ' ' + (this.class || ''); 
    }

    @HostBinding('attr.aria-hidden')
    public get ariaHidden() { return true }

    constructor() {

    }
}
```

**Where it is used**

```
<button class="ui-button" (click)="importOrders()">Import Orders</button>
<div class="status-bar"></div>
<div class="order-list">
    <div *ngFor="let item of orders" class="success-{{item.success}}">
        <div class="icon-block"><i [fa]="item.icon"></i></div>
        <span>{{item.order.email}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Error**

```
Can't bind to 'fa' since it isn't a known property of 'i'. ("">
    <div *ngFor="let item of orders" class="success-{{item.success}}">
        <div class="icon-block"><i [ERROR ->][fa]="item.icon"></i></div>
        <span>{{item.order.email}}</span>
    </div>
"): ng:///PagesModule/OrdersComponent.html@4:29 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'fa' since it isn't a known property of 'i'. ("">
    <div *ngFor="let item of orders" class="success-{{item.success}}">
        <div class="icon-block"><i [ERROR ->][fa]="item.icon"></i></div>
        <span>{{item.order.email}}</span>
    </div>
"): ng:///PagesModule/OrdersComponent.html@4:29
```

Comment: odd. I couldn't recreate the problem. https://plnkr.co/edit/jYhtkDr62cc6P46AGuoT?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<i [attr.fa]="item.icon"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens becouse tag 'i' no contain the property [fa], if you component has the selector a[fa] you must put for call her . In Angular terminology component  no contains the property [fa]

Try this, rename the directive to ifa: selector: '[ifa]'

```
   <i ifa fa="item.icon"></i>
```

or

```
  <i ifa [fa]="item.icon"></i>
```

or change to selector [fa] and put

```
 <i  [fa]="item.icon"></i>
```

Comment: But as you can see, tag `i` definitely contains property `fa`. I literally copied the code from another project and it worked in the other project. My selector is `i[fa]`.

Comment: The selector of directive is i[fa] but when you put <i [fa]="item.icon"></i> Angular see it how a property of tag i and html tag i no contains fa property

Comment: I tried removing the element part of the selector, that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had moved the template to a different module and didn't understand how the modules work together.

This page goes into detail about the ins and outs of NgModule: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule

The gist of it is that each module has to export its declarations in order for other modules to use them. The recommended method is to make a CommonModule that every module imports in their imports array (including AppModule, if needed) and declare and export all your little directives, components, and pipes in there.

You don't want to import AppModule into the other modules, thus the need for a CommonModule.